# LibGDX NullPointerException at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.I18NBundle.createBundleImpl with locales

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am getting **NullPointerException** when trying to create bundle for locale strings in some android devices, with **SDK 27, 28 and 29**.

My code to load locale strings:

```
 public LocaleManager() {
    localeDefault = Locale.getDefault();
    baseFileHandle = Gdx.files.internal("location/string");
}

public void loadLocales() {
    if (localeDefault.getLanguage().equals("en")) {
        locale = new Locale("", "", "");
    } else if (localeDefault.getLanguage().equals("es")) {
        locale = new Locale("es", "", "");
    }
    myBundle = I18NBundle.createBundle(baseFileHandle, locale, ENCODING);
}
```

When calling `createBundle(baseFileHandle, locale, ENCODING)` it throws **NullPointerException** because of that from `IN18Bundle.java` class:

```
private static I18NBundle createBundleImpl (FileHandle baseFileHandle, Locale locale, String encoding) {
    if (baseFileHandle == null || locale == null || encoding == null) throw new NullPointerException();

    I18NBundle bundle = null;
    I18NBundle baseBundle = null;
    Locale targetLocale = locale;
...
```

It seems `baseFileHandle` is null when is initialized from `Gdx.files.internal("location/string");`, but it only occurs on some devices.

Any help?